# How to use a particular font from a given (built in) family with Tailwind?

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I want to apply the font "Courier New" to my text by using Tailwind.

In the documentation, I see that it is available under `font-mono` https://tailwindcss.com/docs/font-family

But when I apply font-mono, its applying all of these families, how do I apply "Courier New" in particular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `font-mono` font families in the [Tailwind configuration file](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/font-family#font-families):

```js
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        'mono': ['"Courier New"', 'monospace'],
      },
    },
  },
};
```

You should keep the `monospace` font as a fallback for when Courier New is not available.

Also, you can add new font families within the `theme.extend.fontFamily` object (`theme.extend.fontFamily.foobar` translates to the `font-foobar` CSS class), so it might be more sensible to create a new family entirely for your Courier New-specific use case instead of overriding a default.

Comment: I found the Next.js documentation a bit confusing—thanks for the assist! Indeed, it's not `'mono': [var(--font-courier-new)]`